# Joomla 3.x Administrator datetime doesn't match frontend

Tags: datetime, joomla, timezone, joomla3.0, administrator

I've burn too much time on that one. I really need help.

We have Joomla 3.2.3 installed on a dedicated server.
Our client ask us to set the timezone to New York.

The timezone is setted from UTC (default from joomla) to `America/New_York` on `php.ini`.
In the config section in the administrator panel, we've make sure that the timezone was matching with php.ini.

The problem is that there is an offset of 4 hours only in the administrator panel.
If you save a content publish date to `2014-05-28 02:34:00`, in MYSQL and in the frontend, it will show `2014-05-28 11:34:00`.

This is a timezone issue for sure, but I can't find where I did wrong. Can anyone help?

Again, what I did so far is:

- Set timezone to America/New_York in php.ini
- Select New York in "System - Global Configuration - Server"
- Check in each user profile to set timezone to default.

MySQL and Frontend display -4hours offset.

Thanks for any help. Very appreciated!

-------- UPDATES -----

Problem is finally solved.

Joomla stores date in GMT / UTC format.
I had to reconverted the timezone to display it correctly.

So the lesson would be : "Do not use the raw data from MySQL DB, some need to be converted before".

Comment: And what is it that you expect to see instead?  New York is indeed currently 4 hours behind UTC.  It will switch to 5 hours behind UTC when daylight saving time ends in November.

Comment: I expect to have the date displayed the same way in both frentend and backend. The frontend is correct. It show the same date as in mysql raw data. In administrator, there is an offset of minus 4 hours. Eachtime you want to have a publish date, you need to calculate the offset. I checked everywhere and all the settings are on the correct timezone. So there is a place somewhere where it calls UTC/GMT instead of the default New York.

Comment: You should answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is finally solved.

Joomla stores date in GMT / UTC format. I had to reconverted the timezone to display it correctly.

So the lesson would be : "Do not use the raw data from MySQL DB, some need to be converted before".